# Index <pinecone.data.index.Index object at 0x000002655A3E1CD0> does not exist

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, pinecone

i kept trying and getting index not exisit even i hve the same index in my pinecone account but still facing same isssue

````
i kept trying and getting index not exisit even i hve the same index in my pinecone account but still facing same isssue 

from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.embeddings import huggingface,HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
import pinecone
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from pinecone import Pinecone
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader,DirectoryLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain import text_splitter
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.llms import CTransformers```
````

#etract data from pdf
def load_pdf(data):
loader= DirectoryLoader(data,glob="*.pdf",loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
documents=loader.load()
return documents

extracted_data=load_pdf("data/")

def text_split(extracted_data):
text_splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500,chunk_overlap=20)
text_chunk=text_splitter.split_documents(extracted_data)
return text_chunk```

```
text_chunks=text_split(extracted_data)
print("length of my chunk :" ,len(text_chunks))

embeddings=download_hugging_face_embeddings()


query_result=embeddings.embed_query("hello world")
print("length",len(query_result))

#i kept trying and getting index not exisit even i hve the same #index in my pinecone account but still facing same isssue 

from pinecone import Pinecone
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone as PC
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone as PineconeVectorStore
# initialize connection to pinecone (get API key at app.pinecone.io)
api_key = API_KEY

pc = Pinecone(api_key=api_key)
index_name =pc.Index("medical-chatbot")

pc.list_indexes()
docsearch = PineconeVectorStore(
    index_name, embeddings, [t.page_content for t in text_chunks]
)

pc = Pinecone(api_key=api_key)
index_name =pc.Index("medical-chatbot")
docsearch=Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embeddings)

query = "What are Allergies"

docs=docsearch.similarity_search(query, k=3)

print("Result", docs)
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post to include the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`langchain.vectorstores` has been deprecated.

To update/intall the packages run the following command in terminal

```
%pip install --upgrade --quiet  langchain-pinecone langchain-openai langchain
```

Update your code like this:

```
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "api-key"
os.environ["PINECONE_API_KEY"] = "pinecone-key"

from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

loader = PyPDFLoader("beyond-good-and-evil.pdf")
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
# print(docs)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore

index_name = "companion"

docsearch = PineconeVectorStore.from_documents(docs, embeddings, index_name=index_name)

query = "What is the meaning life??"
docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
print(docs[0].page_content)
```

Results :

[image]

Comment: Index <pinecone.data.index.Index object at 0x0000019D5848DA90> does not exist. the index is there but still same issue

Comment: How did you create the index?

Comment: yes its there on my account

Comment: on the website there is button to create under my account name

Comment: Can you run the following code by putting your API key and see if the index is showing up? 
"

from pinecone import Pinecone

pc = Pinecone(api_key="YOUR_API_KEY")
pc.list_indexes() "

Comment: Also did you create the index on serverless?

Comment: {'indexes': [{'dimension': 384,
              'host': 'medical-chatbot-i0afjip.svc.gcp-starter.pinecone.io',
              'metric': 'cosine',
              'name': 'medical-chatbot',
              'spec': {'pod': {'environment': 'gcp-starter',
                               'pod_type': 'starter',
                               'pods': 1,
                               'replicas': 1,
                               'shards': 1}},
              'status': {'ready': True, 'state': 'Ready'}}]} the index is there but i think the problem is  PineconeVectorStore.from_texts

Comment: still the same issue I'm facing

Comment: Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: Also tell me how do you create embeddings?

Comment: I've fixed a typo in my answer.

Comment: If the embeddings is OpenAIEmbeddings then you might want to replace embeddings in  PineconeVectorStore(...) with embeddings.embed_query .

Comment: Did it work? I've finally found a much better alternative solution.

Comment: no still facing isssue for my embdding :def text_split(extracted_data):
    text_splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500,chunk_overlap=20)
    text_chunk=text_splitter.split_documents(extracted_data)
    return text_chunk


text_chunks=text_split(extracted_data)
print("length of my chunk :" ,len(text_chunks))


def download_hugging_face_embeddings():
    embeddings=HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    return embeddings


embeddings=download_hugging_face_embeddings()

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: Notify if there is any issue.

Comment: i have upated the code with whole original one please check and let me know

Comment: I've updated the code and ran to check the results myself. I'm using OpenAIEmbeddings, replace those with yours and update it's api-key accordingly with the correct name.

Comment: hi i got htis erorr now :PineconeApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Wed, 28 Feb 2024 03:32:43 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '103', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-pinecone-request-latency-ms': '692', 'x-pinecone-request-id': '9087112463208363519', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '5', 'server': 'envoy'})
HTTP response body: {"code":3,"message":"Vector dimension 1536 does not match the dimension of the index 384","details":[]}

Comment: This is because the vector dimensions that you've setup in your pinecone medical-chatbot were 384 which does not match the vector dimensions of the download_hugging_face_embeddings() which are 1536.

Comment: Simply change the vector dimensions of you medical-chatbot to 1536 on your account. If you can't change it then create a new index with correct vector dimension number.

Comment: if you've found my answer useful then please let me know.